# How can I plot the TCP RTT graph in Wireshark?

Tags: tcp, wireshark

I'm suspecting one of our Host is not performing well in the TCP protocol Level.I have tried to plot the TCP RTT graph using tcp.analysis option in the IO graph.However,I'm not finding the right option to plot the RTT in the IO graph.

How can I plot the average RTT of tcp in Wireshark? This is what I have got so far.

[image]

Comment: I am not sure if this might be the thing you are looking for, but in the `Statistics` menu you find an entry `TCP Stream Graphs` and there you'll find an entry `Roun Trip Time`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just go to the `Statistics`menu and then to the entry `TCP Stream Graphs`
There you will find the entry `TCP Stream Graphs`, from where you can choose `Round Trip Time`.
This might do the Job.